# Azure Data Factory - Changing A file name by stripping of date time

Tags: json, azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline setup that gets a filename list from blob, sets variable as ARAY to do this, then just copies to new location with a new name.  For example file in might be scottdatetest_01_01_20.txt and I need scottdatetest.txt.

My JSOn is as follows and the output shows that it did what I wanted, however the file has arrived in the sink with same name as source.  What am i missing to get it to write the name as displayed in the output?

```
       "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "wildcardFileName": "*",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                        "copyBehavior": {
                            "value": "@substring(string(variables('Filenames')),0,indexof(string(variables('Filenames')),'_'))",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                        "quoteAllText": true,
                        "fileExtension": ".txt"
                    }
                },
                "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        },
```

OUTPUT from Debug:

```
},
"sink": {
    "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
    "storeSettings": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
        "copyBehavior": "[{\"name\":\"scottdatetest"
    },
    "formatSettings": {
        "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
        "quoteAllText": true,
        "fileExtension": ".txt"
    }
```

Also I want to run this for multiple files, I have tried and got the following output, which looks like its trying to write it in to 1 file and not the folder:

{
    "source": {
        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
            "recursive": true,
            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false,
            "prefix": "[{\"name\":\"BUPAUKStandardInvoicePartnerConnectorExpense_1252_01102020.csv\",\"type\":\"File\"},{\"name\":\"BUPAUKStandardInvoicePartnerConnectorMiscFee_1254_01102020.csv\",\"type\":\"File\"}]"
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
        }
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
        "storeSettings": {
            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
            "copyBehavior": "[{\"name\":\"BUPAUKStandardInvoicePartnerConnectorExpense.csv"
        },
        "formatSettings": {
            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
            "quoteAllText": true,
            "fileExtension": ".csv"
        }
    },
    "enableStaging": false
}

Comment: just to add I am trying this for multiple files and they seem to want to only write back to the 1 file, here is the output from debug run: